# Gmail-API Threads.list is not returning messages in the response

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api

I'm trying to use the Gmail-API to get all the threads from a user and to have all of the messages in that thread by using threads.list. In the gmail documentation, it states that the following is the response from hitting this endpoint:

```
{
 "threads": [
   users.threads Resource
 ],
 "nextPageToken": string,
 "resultSizeEstimate": unsigned integer
}
```

I have a simple function to hit this endpoint

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

/**
 * Lists the threads in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */

export function listThreads(auth,fn) {
    const gmail =  google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});

    gmail.users.threads.list({
      userId: 'me',
      q: 'to:abc@abc.com '
    }, (err, res) => {
      if (err) throw 'The API returned an error: ' + err;
      
      // fn is a callback used to return data to the handler since
      // the res object is in the callback of thread.list
      fn(res)
    });

  }
```

The following is what I get as a response (I replaced the actual email with abc and replaced my token for privacy):

```
{
    "gmail": {
        "config": {
            "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/threads?q=to%3Aabc%40abc.com",
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip",
                "User-Agent": "google-api-nodejs-client/0.7.2 (gzip)",
                "Authorization": "Bearer 123456",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            "params": {
                "q": "to:abc@abc.com"
            },
            "responseType": "json"
        },
        "data": {
            "threads": [
                {
                    "id": "173bf0efdd1f1dc4",
                    "snippet": "Hello abc, Attached are the screenshots of my website for the requirements. Please send me an email with all of the information I&#39;m asking for in the forms. For the colors, here is the site to",
                    "historyId": "4759550"
                }
            ],
            "resultSizeEstimate": 1
        },
        "headers": {
            "alt-svc": "h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"",
            "cache-control": "private",
            "connection": "close",
            "content-encoding": "gzip",
            "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            "date": "Thu, 20 Aug 2020 01:13:07 GMT",
            "server": "ESF",
            "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
            "vary": "Origin, X-Origin, Referer",
            "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
            "x-frame-options": "SAMEORIGIN",
            "x-xss-protection": "0"
        },
        "status": 200,
        "statusText": "OK"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the messages property of res.data.threads is completely missing. I would appreciate any guidance.

Thank You

Comment: I should have added a link to the documenation where you can see the values for user.threads resource: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, in order to retrieve all messages from each thread, it is required to use the method of "Users.threads: get". When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const gmail =  google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});

gmail.users.threads.list(
  {
    userId: "me",
    q: "to:abc@abc.com ",
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw "The API returned an error: " + err;
    Promise.all(
      res.data.threads.map(({ id }) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          gmail.users.threads.get({ userId: "me", id }, (err, res) => {
            if (err) rejects(err);
            resolve(res.data);
          });
        });
      })
    ).then((res) => {
      fn(res);
    });
  }
);
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already been able to retrieve the email using Gmail API.

#### References:

-[Users.threads: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list)
-[Users.threads: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get)

Comment: This works! I must have missed this in the documentation. I thought the messages were supposed to come with the response.

Comment: @ajohnson10209 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.